# Squid didn't cache artifacts, which was downloaded from remote repository with authentication

Tags: squid

I have a latest Squid, installed in my network.
SSL bump and other options has been configured. Artifacts, which I download from HTTPS sites, are cacheing successfully(as example https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/3.5.1/kafka_2.12-3.5.1.tgz).
But also I need to download files from external source, which is required authentication.
I tried to download it via `curl --user "name:password" https://****`. File has been download successfully, but didn't stores in cache, I got only TCP_MISS in log.

Could you help me, please, with solution?

squid config:

```
acl localnet src 127.0.0.1/32
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 21
acl Safe_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 70
acl Safe_ports port 210
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535
acl Safe_ports port 280
acl Safe_ports port 488
acl Safe_ports port 591

acl Safe_ports port 777
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all

acl intermediate_fetching transaction_initiator certificate-fetching
http_access allow intermediate_fetching

http_port 3128 tcpkeepalive=60,30,3 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=20MB tls-cert=/etc/squid/bump.crt tls-key=/etc/squid/bump.key cipher=HIGH:MEDIUM:!LOW:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS options=NO_TLSv1,NO_SSLv3,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE tls-dh=prime256v1:/etc/squid/bump_dhparam.pem

cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid/ 32000 16 256
maximum_object_size 6 GB
cache_mem 8192 MB
cache allow all

visible_hostname proxy.COMPANY.local
strip_query_terms off
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/security_file_certgen -s /var/lib/squid/ssl_db -M 20MB
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
ssl_bump bump all
```